# How to efficiently Join / Group these tables with one to many relationships

Tags: oracle

Been stuck on this for hours now. Right now, i am trying to group values for HR1 and HR2 in the same row by Submission_Id

For example, What I am getting is below:

```
Submission_Id   Posting_Type   Response_Type  Day_Of_Year    GMT_Offset   HR1         HR2
2460037         Daily          UTC0           602014         5            08-03-18 13:02:17 
2460037         Daily          UTC0           602014         5                       08-03-18 13:02:17
2460037         Daily          UTC1           602014         5            08-03-18 13:02:17 
2460037         Daily          UTC1           602014         5                       08-03-18 13:02:17
```

What I am trying to get is below:

```
Submission_Id   Posting_Type   Response_Type  Day_Of_Year    GMT_Offset   HR1                              HR2
2460037         Daily          UTC0           602014         5            12-MAR-18 08-03-18 13:02:17      12-MAR-18 08-03-18 13:02:17
2460037          Daily         UTC1           602014         5            12-MAR-18 08-03-18 13:02:17      12-MAR-18 08-03-18 13:02:17
```

The Query i've been finagling with is below:

```
select 
   s.submission_id
 , CASE WHEN FL.FORM_LINE_ID = '2001'
    THEN 'Same-Day'
    WHEN FL.FORM_LINE_ID = '2002'
    THEN 'Daily'
    END             Posting_Type
 , ff.form_field_tx     Response_Type
 , v.data_date          Day_Of_Year
 , v.utc_offset         GMT_Offset
 , v.create_dt          Posted_Date
 , CASE WHEN FF.FORM_FIELD_TX IN ('UTC0', 'UTC1', 'UTC2', 'UTCD') and v.HR_NUM = 1
    THEN to_char(v.HR, 'DD-MM-YY HH24:MI:SS')
    WHEN FF.FORM_FIELD_TX IN ('Tutoring', 'Studying') and v.HR_NUM = 1
    THEN Value_Tx
    END             HR1
 , CASE WHEN FF.FORM_FIELD_TX IN ('UTC0', 'UTC1', 'UTC2', 'UTCD') and v.HR_NUM = 2
    THEN to_char(v.HR, 'DD-MM-YY HH24:MI:SS')
    WHEN FF.FORM_FIELD_TX IN ('Time Reading', 'Time Working Out') and v.HR_NUM = 2
    THEN Value_Tx
    END             HR2
 from submission s
 inner join submission_value sv on s.submission_id = sv.submission_id
 inner join value v on  v.value_id = sv.value_id
 inner join form_field ff on sv.form_field_id = ff.form_field_id
 inner join form_line fl on ff.form_line_id = fl.form_line_id
 group by s.submission_id, ff.form_field_tx, v.data_date   , v.utc_offset, v.create_dt ;
```

Sample Data is as follows:

```
Submission:
 Submission_Id       Submission_Dt        Submission_Name          Create_Dt
 24600037            03-15-2018            20180315                11-MAR-18

Submission_Value
 Submission_value_Id    Submission_ID     Value_ID            Form_Field_Id
  990                   24600037          5550                777
  991                   24600037          5551                777
  992                   24600037          5552                777
  993                   24600037          5553                777

Form_Field
  Form_Field_Id      Form_Field_Tx       Create_DT           Form_Line_Id
  1001               UTC0                15-MAR-18           2001
  1002               UTC1                15-MAR-18           2001

Form_line
Form_Line_Id         Form_Line_Tx
  2001               Example1
  2002               Example2

Value
 Value_Id     Value_Tx    HR_num  UTC_Offset     Data_Date     HR     Create_Dt
   5551      Test Value    UTC0       4            602015   sysdate    sysdate
   5552      Test Value    UTC1       4            602015   sysdate    sysdate

Create Table Submission
(
  Submission_Id varchar2(10)
, Submission_Dt date
, Submission_name varchar2(30)
, Create_dt date
);
insert into Submission (Submission_id, Submission_Dt, Submission_Name, Create_DT)
Values('24600037', '03-15-2018', '20180315', '11-MAR-18)';

Create Table Value
(
  Value_Id number
, value_tx varchar2(50)
, hr_num   varchar2(10)
, utc_offset number
, data_date varchar2(10)
, hr       datetime
, create_dt date
 );

insert into value (Value_id, value_tx, hr_num, utc_offset, data_date, hr, create_dt)  
 values (5551, 'Test Value', 'UTC0', '4', '602015', sysdate, sysdate);

insert into value (Value_id, value_tx, hr_num, utc_offset, data_date, hr, create_dt)  
 values (5552, 'Test Value', 'UTC1', '4','602015', sysdate, sysdate);

 Create Table Submission_Value
 (
  Submission_value_Id   Number
 , Submission_id         Number
 , Value_Id              Number
 , Form_field_Id         Number
 );
 insert into Submission_Value (Submission_Value_Id, Submission_Id, Value_Id, Form_Field_Id)
 values('990', '24600037', '5550', '777');

insert into Submission_Value (Submission_Value_Id, Submission_Id, Value_Id, Form_Field_Id)
 values('991', '24600037', '5551', '777');

insert into Submission_Value (Submission_Value_Id, Submission_Id, Value_Id, Form_Field_Id)
 values('992', '24600037', '5552', '777');

insert into Submission_Value (Submission_Value_Id, Submission_Id, Value_Id, Form_Field_Id)
 values('993', '24600037', '5553', '777');\
Create Table Form_Field
(
   Form_Field_Id      Number
 , Form_Field_Tx      Varchar2(200)
 , Create_DT          Date
 , Form_Line_Id       Number
)
insert into Form_Field (Form_Field_id, Form_Field_Tx, Create_Dt, Form_Line_ID)
values('1001', 'UTC0', '15-MAR-18', '2001');
insert into Form_Field (Form_Field_id, Form_Field_Tx, Create_Dt, Form_Line_ID)
values('1002', 'UTC0', '15-MAR-18', '2001');
Create Table Form_Line
(
 Form_line_id         Number
,Form_line_tx         Varchar2(200)
)

insert into Form_Line (Form_Line_Id, Form_Line_Tx)
values('2001', 'Example1');
insert into Form_Line (Form_Line_Id, Form_Line_Tx)
values('2002', 'Example2');
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74659/discussion-on-question-by-icerabbit-how-to-efficiently-join-group-these-table).

Answer (score 1):

With the following modifications, I believe your basic query should work:

```
select    
   s.submission_id   
 , CASE WHEN FL.FORM_LINE_ID = '2001'   
    THEN 'Same-Day'   
    WHEN FL.FORM_LINE_ID = '2002'   
    THEN 'Daily'   
    END             Posting_Type   
 , ff.form_field_tx     Response_Type   
 , v.data_date          Day_Of_Year   
 , v.utc_offset         GMT_Offset   
 , v.create_dt          Posted_Date   
 , MAX(CASE WHEN FF.FORM_FIELD_TX IN ('UTC0', 'UTC1', 'UTC2', 'UTCD') and v.HR_NUM = 1   
    THEN to_char(v.HR, 'DD-MM-YY HH24:MI:SS')   
    WHEN FF.FORM_FIELD_TX IN ('Tutoring', 'Studying') and v.HR_NUM = 1   
    THEN Value_Tx   
    END)             HR1   
 , MAX(CASE WHEN FF.FORM_FIELD_TX IN ('UTC0', 'UTC1', 'UTC2', 'UTCD') and v.HR_NUM = 2   
    THEN to_char(v.HR, 'DD-MM-YY HH24:MI:SS')   
    WHEN FF.FORM_FIELD_TX IN ('Time Reading', 'Time Working Out') and v.HR_NUM = 2   
    THEN Value_Tx   
    END)             HR2   
 from submission s   
 inner join submission_value sv on s.submission_id = sv.submission_id   
 inner join value v on  v.value_id = sv.value_id   
 inner join form_field ff on sv.form_field_id = ff.form_field_id   
 inner join form_line fl on ff.form_line_id = fl.form_line_id   
 group by s.submission_id, FL.FORM_LINE_ID, ff.form_field_tx, v.data_date   , v.utc_offset, v.create_dt
```

Note that the error `Not a GROUP BY expression` seems not to be very helpful. It seems to mean (in your case, at least) that you have expressions in your `SELECT` list that include columns that are neither in the `GROUP BY` list, nor part of an aggregate function.

The changes are:

- Adding the field `FL.FORM_LINE_ID` to the `GROUP BY` expression. This makes the `PostingType` expression in the `SELECT` list valid.
- Putting both the `SELECT` list expressions labeled `HR1` and `HR2` in an aggregate function (I used `MAX()`).

With some tinkering, I finally got an abbreviated version of the above query to work. I modified some of your source data (the `value_id`s in `submission_value` didn't exist in `value`, so there were no rows returned initially), and I removed both `HR1` and `HR2`. With `HR1` and `HR2` left in, the query still failed. This would appear to be because `hr_num` isn't a number. (In the comments, you indicated the field previously labeled `hr_utc` should be `hr_num`; however, it appears that not just the name, but the contents are a problem).

Note - You may want to work with actual dates instead of dates converted to strings in the `HR1` and `HR2`. You can convert the output of the `MAX()` function to a string if needed, but if you're comparing dates, you probably want them to sort out differently than how the text strings are formatted. If so, you may also want to consider using `MIN()` instead of `MAX()` for some values.

Here's my [LiveSQL script](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/gey60vgl7bn2x1nsfn3hkjnsp) that shows I can at least get all the grouped fields to return a line with the current test data....